# ipairs package in R - too many rows in layout, limit 50

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to use the ipairs package in R and having some issues making an image scatterplot. My dataset originally had about 80 columns, but I cut it down to 49 thinking it was causing the issue. After this I still receive the error. Below is my code:

```
> length(names(ameshouse))
[1] 49

> ameshouse $SalePrice <- as.factor(ameshouse $SalePrice)
> zmax <- ipairs(ameshouse, pixs=.5, main="Ames Housing")

Error in layout(lom, widths = c(rep(1, nc), d.legend, w.legend), heights = c(h.main, : 
  too many rows in layout, limit 50
```

The dataset does have about 2900 rows but surely that isn't the issue, anyone have any suggestions or possibly another package that is superior to ipairs?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Through trial and error I found that the problem was the number of columns. The max amount of columns is 21 for anyone who has the same issue.